# How to render a composite component using a custom renderer?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, renderer

I would like to know how to render a composite component, through Java,
I mean I have:

```
<myowntags:selectOneRadio>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value0" itemLabel="This is the value 0" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value1" itemLabel="This is the value 1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value2" itemLabel="This is the value 2" />
</myowntags:selectOneRadio>
```

or

```
<myowntags:selectOneRadio>
  <f:selectItems  value="#{controller.items}"  />
</myowntags:selectOneRadio>
```

and I would like to create a Java class to render it.

I know how to render a custom component without using composite, but since, to render a component I have to specify some values on the block:

```
<renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.SelectBoolean</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Checkbox</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.myapp.CustomCheckboxRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

then I get lost, because I don't know the values of those parameters
inside the render tag for a composite component.

Thanks in advance,
Angel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to have a backing component which implements [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) and returns `"javax.faces.NamingContainer"` as component family. This is required by composite components, you can't change that part. The [`UINamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) implementation already does that, so if you can just extend from it.

```
@FacesComponent("mySelectOneRadio")
public class MySelectOneRadio extends UINamingContainer {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you rather want to extend from `UISelectOne`, then you'd have to implement the `NamingContainer` interface and make sure that you return [`UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html#COMPONENT_FAMILY) in the `getFamily()` override.

Then, you need to specify it in `<cc:interface componentType>`.

```
<cc:interface componentType="mySelectOneRadio">
```

---

Note that at this step you can already perform the rendering (encoding) through Java. Just override the `encodeChildren()` method.

```
@FacesComponent("mySelectOneRadio")
public class MySelectOneRadio extends UINamingContainer {

    @Override
    public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("div", this);
        writer.writeText("hello world", null);
        writer.endElement("div");
    }

}
```

---

Coming back to your concrete question, you'd thus like to have a standalone `Renderer` class for this. That's fine. For that you need to extend `Renderer`:

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily=UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY, rendererType=MySelectOneRadioRenderer.RENDERER_TYPE)
public class MySelectOneRadioRenderer extends Renderer {

    public static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "com.example.MySelectOneRadio";

    @Override
    public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("div", component);
        writer.writeText("hello world", null);
        writer.endElement("div");
    }

}
```

The backing component should be changed as follows in order to properly register this renderer as the default renderer (don't override `getRendererType()` method! otherwise you or anyone else would be unable to change this by `<renderer>` in `faces-config.xml`):

```
@FacesComponent("myComposite")
public class MyComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    public MyComposite() {
        // Set default renderer.
        setRendererType(MySelectOneRadioRenderer.RENDERER_TYPE);
    }

}
```

Note that thanks to the `@FacesRenderer`, you don't need to hassle with `faces-config.xml`.

---

Whatever way you choose to encode the children, you can get component's children just by `UIComponent#getChildren()`. When you're inside `MySelectOneRadio` component:

```
if (getChildCount() > 0) {
    for (UICompnent child : getChildren()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or when you're inside `MySelectOneRadioRenderer` renderer:

```
if (component.getChildCount() > 0) {
    for (UICompnent child : component.getChildren()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To delegate to the component's own default rendering, invoke `super.encodeChildren()` or `component.encodeChildren()`. To delegate to child's own default rendering, invoke `child.encodeAll()`.

#### See also:

- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/jsf-what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-rend)

Comment: Hello @BalusC, your answer was very useful, also I would like to know how do I pass the value of the selected `<selectItem />` to a controller when the user clicks on a `<h:commandButton />`

Comment: Is there a way to render the `<cc:implementation/>` section of a composite-component form/with a custom renderer ? With a custom renderer `<h:outputScript target="head"/>` tags in `<cc:implementation/>` seem to be taken into account but it's not the case of simple text literals.