# Need help on finishing the implementation of custom component with composite

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component, composite-component

I'm implementing a custom component with composite.
The source code of my composite compoment is only as follow:

```
<cc:interface componentType="selectOneRadio"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
              xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <cc:attribute name="direction" default="next" />
</cc:interface>
```

as you can see I don't use the `implementation` section, but it is no problem for me if I have to use it.

Then, I render it's content with Java as follows:

```
public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
   ...
}
```

This control will generate an integer value based on the value of the attribute with name: "direction". If it's value is "next" then the generated value is the current day of the month plus 1 and if it's value is "back" then the generated value is the current day of the month minus 1.

I would like to know how could I pass that generated value to the backing bean when the user clicks on a `<h:commandButton />` I add after my custom component?

Do I need to use `<f:ajax />` or something like that?

Other question by the way, could I render my composite component with Java and `<cc:implementation />` at the same time (mixing)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the form submit processing job in the `decode()` method.

```
@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context) {
    // ...
}
```

You could get an attribute as a `ValueExpression` by the inherited `getValueExpression()` method. You can perform a "set" operation using `ValueExpression#setValue()`. E.g.

```
<my:composite ... value="#{bean.foo}" />
```

with

```
ValueExpression value = getValueExpression("value");
value.setValue(context.getElContext(), newValue);
```

will set `newValue` accordingly on the property represented by `#{bean.foo}`.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, with your suggestions above I can pass the generated value to the backing controller, thank you. But with my question above I simplified my real situation too much and then I need a little complement to your answer. My real situation is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526211/how-to-render-a-composite-component-using-a-custom-renderer) and I need to get (inside the decode method) the value of the selected: `<selectItem />`. Each `<selectItem />` is rendered as a radio button (`<input type="radio" ...`).

Comment: Inside decode, you are supposed to grab the submitted value from the request parameter map. E.g. `externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get(clientId)`.

Comment: thank you very much @BalusC, now it is working pretty good ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) I forgot to add, model value actually needs to be updated in `processUpdates()` method override. This will only be invoked when the validation has passed.

Comment: So, do I have to move: `ValueExpression value = getValueExpression("value"); value.setValue(context.getElContext(), newValue);` from `decode(...)` method to `processUpdates()` method?. As I have it right now it works, but I don't know if it is more advisable to move there?