# Why should I use createComponent instead of creating the instance myself?

Tags: jsf-2

This is more of a conceptual question.

I had to work on a functionality that had to create a dynamic `h:dataTable`. And whenever I created a component, I did something similar to this:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
                      .createComponent(DataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);
```

Using the `FacesContext` to create everything for me.

However I could just as simply have done this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

The reason I did it in the first way is that all the tutorials and material I read while developing did it that way, but I never got a clear answer why.

Is there an actual reason why the first is better than the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Application#createComponent()` adds an extra abstract layer allowing runtime polymorphism and pluggability. The concrete implementation is configurable by `<component>` entry in `faces-config.xml` which could in turn be provided via a JAR. This allows changing implementation without rewriting/recompiling the code.

It's exactly like as how JDBC API works: you don't do `new SomeDriver()`, but you do `Class.forName(someDriverClassName)` which allows the driver to not be a compiletime dependency and thus your JDBC code to be portable across many DB vendors without rewriting/recompiling.

However, if the application is for "internal usage" only and not intented to be distributable (and thus all the code is always full under you control), then runtime polymorphism has not a so big advantage and may add (very minor) overhead.

#### See also:

- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-renderer-t/)

Comment: Oh, I see now. It actually makes perfect sense, I just never thought of it from that angle. The link you added as reference was also a very big mind opener. Thanks again, @BalusC! I actually thought that it'd be you who would answer this. Good thing I was right :-) Cheers!

Comment: I always thought that if you used 'new SomeComponent()' things like adding ajax behaviours would not work... Never to old to learn