# java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered only in MyFaces

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, myfaces

I ran into an issue when trying to work with a WAS 9 server which has MyFaces. My application works with Mojarra  on tomcat.

A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that can be tested in tomcat (please ignore anything to do with primefaces):

Mojarra : https://github.com/ravihariharan/primefaces-test
MyFaces : https://github.com/ravihariharan/primefaces-test-myfaces

Reference files : TestNull.java, BaseBean.java , testnull.xhtml

Oracle Mojarra  2.2.15 vs Apache MyFaces issue 2.2.12

```
public class TestNull extends BaseBean {

private Boolean testNullRender; 
//This has not be been instantiated on purpose

public TestNull() {
    super();
}

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
   //HtmlPanelGroup panel = new HtmlPanelGroup();
   HtmlPanelGroup panel = (HtmlPanelGroup) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
            .createComponent(HtmlPanelGroup.COMPONENT_TYPE);

    String valueExpression = "#{testNull.testNullRender}";
    panel.setValueExpression(PropertyConstants.RENDERED, createValueExpression(valueExpression, Boolean.class));

    addComponent("form:panelId", panel);
}

public Boolean getTestNullRender() {
    return testNullRender;
}

public void setTestNullRender(Boolean testNullRender) {
    this.testNullRender = testNullRender;
}
}
```

**Error only in MyFaces :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException


phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:1212)

- Stack Trace

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:1212)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChildren(RendererUtils.java:688)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGroupRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGroupRendererBase.java:150)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:555)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1891)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:313)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
```

Addition Update for MyFaces:
Declarative ValueExpression working:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelId0" rendered="#{testNull.testNullRender}">
```

Issue only with programmatic ValueExpression

```
String valueExpression = "#{testNull.testNullRender}";
        panel.setValueExpression(PropertyConstants.RENDERED, createValueExpression(valueExpression, Boolean.class));

        addComponent("form:panelId", panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you change your testNullRender to a primitive. I'm not sure if Boolean as object is supported in the specs.

Comment: I have been trying to figure the same since the two implementations of the specification Mojarra &  MyFaces have different behavior and it seemed its a bug in MyFaces.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug. What does rendered=null mean? true and false are actually the only possible values IMO.

Comment: The Declarative ValueExpression works similar to Mojarra. The issue is only with Programmatic ValueExpression in MyFaces.

Comment: This issue came to my notice because we use programmatic ui components  for a dynamic  questionnaire with a custom data structure.

Comment: <h:panelGroup id="panelId0" rendered="#{testNull.testNullRender}"> in the xhmtl should have also give the same error in MyFaces. But it works without any Exception.

Comment: Did you try the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610655/why-should-i-use-createcomponent-instead-of-creating-the-instance-myself ?

Comment: Same error on using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
                .createComponent(HtmlPanelGroup.COMPONENT_TYPE);

Comment: I tried your example and as i already mentioned, it works fine if testNullRender is a primitive and can not return null.

Comment: I can see some change in the Expression Language. But since EL Spec 3.0 is part of tomcat i still could not figure why it would differ between Mojarra & MyFaces.

Comment: Expression Language 2.1
1.18.5 Coerce A to Boolean
If A is null or "", return false
Otherwise, if A is a Boolean, return A
Otherwise, if A is a String, and Boolean.valueOf(A) does not throw an
exception, return it

Comment: Expression Language  3.0 


1.23.5 Coerce A to Boolean or boolean
If A is null and the target type is not the primitive type boolean, return null
If A is null or "", return false
Otherwise, if A is a Boolean, return A
Otherwise, if A is a String, and Boolean.valueOf(A) does not throw an
exception, return it
Otherwise, error

Comment: since i had a custom data structured based on Object i got around by using String valueExpression = "#{testNull.testNullRender == true}"; which can work for Mojarra & MyFace.