# @Inject-ed value null in @FacesComponent

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, uicomponents

I have the impression that CDI is not working with classes that have a `@javax.faces.component.FacesComponent`. Is this true?

Here's my example, that doesn't work. The `MyInjectableClass` is used at other points in the code where injection is not a problem, so it must be about the `@FacesComponent` annotation I think.

The class I want to inject:

```
@Named
@Stateful
public class MyInjectableClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4556482219775071397L;
}
```

The component which uses that class;

```
@FacesComponent(value = "mycomponents.mytag")
public class MyComponent extends UIComponentBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5656806814384095309L;

    @Inject
    protected MyInjectableClass injectedInstance;


    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        /* injectedInstance is null here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, even for JSF 2.2 `@FacesComponent`, `@FacesValidator` and `@FacesConverter` are not valid injection targets (read [What's new in JSF 2.2?](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/) by Arjan Tijms for more details). As Arjan points out:

> It’s likely that those will be taken into consideration for JSF 2.3 though.

What can you do for now? Well, you've got basically two choices:

1. Handle [CDI injection via lookup](http://dominikdorn.com/2010/04/cdi-weld-manual-bean-lookup/), or switch to EJB and do the [simpler EJB lookup](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator);
2. Annotate tour class with `@Named` instead of `@FacesComponent`, `@Inject` the component the way you did and [register your component in faces-config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079296/1820286). As the UI component instance is created via JSF Application#createComponent(), not via CDI you will also need a custom Application implementation as well (exactly like OmniFaces has for those converters/validators).

And, by the way, you've got two issues with what you've got this far: (1) what is meant by `@Named @Stateful` when the former is from a CDI world and the latter is from EJB world and (2) are you sure you intend to keep state in a faces component that's basically recreated on every request?

Comment: Did you really test #2? UI component instance is created via JSF `Application#createComponent()`, not via CDI. So you basically need a custom `Application` implementation as well (exactly like OmniFaces has for those converters/validators).

Answer (score 1):

`@FacesCompnent` is managed by JSF and injection is not supported into them.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the value in from the XHTML page via a composite component attribute worked for us.