# Use of @ManagedProperty in backing component

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2.2, composite-component

How can I use `@ManagedProperty` in backing component?

This is partner selector composite component. The component checks the typed partner code in the database and fills the partner name if code is valid.

The component:

```
<cc:interface componentType="partnerSelComp">
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Long"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <p:inputText id="id" type="hidden" binding="#{cc.partnerId}"/>                                     
        <p:inputText id="code" binding="#{cc.code}">                     
            <p:ajax event="blur" update="id code name" listener="#{cc.validate}" />
        </p:inputText>            
        <p:inputText id ="name" disabled="true" binding="#{cc.name}" />                   
        <p:message for="code"/>
    </span>
</cc:implementation>
```

In `encodeBegin()` I got NPE because `service` is null:

```
    @FacesComponent("partnerSelComp")
    public class PartnerSelComp extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

        private InputText partnerId;
        private InputText code;    
        private InputText name; 

        @ManagedProperty("#{partnerService}")
        private PartnerService service;

        @Override
        public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
            Partner p=null;
            Long i = (Long) getValue();        

            if (i != null) {            
               p = findPartnerById(service.getList(), i); 
           }
           fill( (i==null) , p); // fills the code and name fields
        }

   ... 


    }
```

This is the bean I'd like to access. (later it will replaced with a JPA query.)

```
@ManagedBean(name = "partnerService")
@ApplicationScoped
public class PartnerService {

    private List<Partner> list;

    public PartnerService() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add( new Partner(1, "A", "Partner A"));
        list.add( new Partner(2, "B", "Partner B"));
        list.add( new Partner(3, "C", "Partner C"));
        list.add( new Partner(4, "D", "Partner D"));
        list.add( new Partner(5, "E", "Partner E"));
        list.add( new Partner(6, "E", "Partner F"));        
    }

    public List<Partner> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Partner> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

**The solution:**

The use of the component:

```
<my:PartnerSelComp value="#{myBean.partnerId}" service="#{partnerService}"/>
```

The component xhtml:

```
    <cc:interface componentType="partnerSelComp">
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Long"/>
        <cc:attribute name="service"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <span id="#{cc.clientId}" style="white-space:nowrap">
            <p:inputText id="id" type="hidden" binding="#{cc.partnerId}"/>                                     
            <p:inputText id="code" binding="#{cc.code}">                     
                <p:ajax event="blur" update="id code name" listener="#{cc.validate}" />
            </p:inputText>            
            <p:inputText id ="name" disabled="true" binding="#{cc.name}" />                   
            <p:message for="code"/>
        </span>
    </cc:implementation>
```

I note, I tried it to pass the reference as attribute default value: `<cc:attribute name="service" default="#{partnerService}"/>` and `<my:PartnerSelComp value="#{myBean.partnerId}"/>` I don't know why but it didn't worked me, I had to set `service` attribute in `my:PartnerSelComp` as you see above.

And the backing component:

```
    @FacesComponent("partnerSelComp")
    public class PartnerSelComp extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

        private InputText partnerId;
        private InputText code;    
        private InputText name; 

        @ManagedProperty("#{partnerService}")
        private PartnerService service;

        @Override
        public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
            Partner p=null;
            Long i = (Long) getValue();        

            PartnerService service = getAttributeValue("service", null );         

            if (i != null) {            
               p = findPartnerById(service.getList(), i); 
           }
           fill( (i==null) , p); // fills the code and name fields
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private <T> T getAttributeValue(String key, T defaultValue) {
            T value = (T) getAttributes().get(key);
            return (value != null) ? value : defaultValue;
        }

   ... 

    }
```

I have to use `getAttributes().get(key)` to get the reference and cast it to `PartnerService`.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Show us your configuration. Most likely your PartnerSelComp component is in a package that isn't loaded by your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load it using the html configuration interface:

```
<cc:interface componentType="partnerSelComp">
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <cc:attribute name="service" default="#{partnerService}"/>
</cc:interface>
```

This is mostly for the usage inside of html implementation as inside of the bean class you would have to get it manually anyway:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get("service");
```

Regarding the direct injection into @FacesComponent it is not possible until next version of JSF (2.3).

A possible workaround would be to use `"@Named` instead of `@FacesComponent` or if you cannot do that, then try out some of the features of the http://omnifaces.org/ library. It enables injection into @FacesConverter so maybe you could also apply it for this annotation.

Comment: Yes, you cannot bind directly the bean, only declare it as an attribute and retrieve as you did.

Comment: i have added some additional info that may be usefull

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223294/inject-ed-value-null-in-facescomponent  There's no injection in backing component. Bad news...

Comment: There **is** injection in backing component in 2.3... **good news**