# How to override primefaces component class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component, faces-config

I would like to override a primefaces component class. So, I have registered the component class in faces-config.xml of WAR project.

```
    <component>
        <component-type>org.primefaces.component.dnd.Droppable</component-type>
        <component-class>com.******.****.****.component.CustomDroppable</component-class>
    </component>
```

This is my new test class:

```
public class CustomDroppable extends Droppable{

    @Override
    public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event) {
        System.out.print("fffffffffffff");
    }

}
```

The application was built anew, but it uses the old class. Why ? What else should I do ?

Answer (score 4):

In the `<component-type>`, you should specify the component type, not the component class. The component type does not necessarily resemble a Java FQN, it can be any kind of string you want. Usually, you can find the right component type in the API documentation of the component class you'd like to replace.

In case of [`org.primefaces.component.dnd.Droppable`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/dnd/Droppable.html) class, it's defined as constant field [`COMPONENT_TYPE`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/dnd/Droppable.html#COMPONENT_TYPE) whose value is [`org.primefaces.component.Droppable`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/constant-values.html#org.primefaces.component.dnd.Droppable.COMPONENT_TYPE) (thus, without `dnd` "subpackage" as compared to the component class).

Fix it accordingly:

```
<component>
    <component-type>org.primefaces.component.Droppable</component-type>
    <component-class>...</component-class>
</component>
```

#### See also:

- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-renderer-t)