# What is the difference between package com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement; and java.sql.PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have connected JAVA application  with MySql .When i wrote PreparedStatement ps = null ;
then two option for import package was showing .The two suggested package was :com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement; and java.sql.PreparedStatement .And , when i import  com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement package they said for casting as shown below .

```
ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Authors(Name) VALUES(?)");
```

And when i used java.sql.PreparedStatement not need for casting in above sentence .

so, My question is : why two different import package are showing ? and why casting needed for com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement   package ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *why two different import package are showing ?*

Because both classes were present in your compiletime classpath and your IDE were trying to be helpful.

---

> *and why casting needed for com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement package ?*

Because `prepareStatement()` is [specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) to return `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, not `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement`.

---

The `java.sql.PreparedStatement` is an **interface** and you should be using this all the time. The MySQL one is a concrete implementation and you should not be tight coupling your JDBC code to the MySQL specific implementation. Otherwise you'd have to make a lot of changes in your code if you ever want to switch the DB server (and thus also the JDBC driver) to a different vendor like PostgreSQL. If you're using the standard JDBC interfaces from `java.sql` package all the time, all you would need to change is only the JDBC URL and maybe also the username and password and some DB-specific SQL statements.

#### See also:

- [When should I use an interface in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586389/when-best-to-use-an-interface-in-java)
- [In simplest terms, what is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550612/in-simplest-terms-what-is-a-factory)

Comment: ... or even if `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` changes name/package, which the mysql developers are at liberty to do, your code will (unnecessarily) break

Comment: @Bohemian That was pretty prescient, because that was exactly what MySQL/Oracle did with MySQL Connector/J 8.