# Why only part Metro Framework packages / artifacts renamed to jakarta and most stay in com.sun.xml?

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework, jakarta-migration

My Gradle WSLD Java source generation plugin still uses `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools` of v2.3.2-1. There is v4.0.0 too:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-tools

but there is no `jaxws-tools` artifact under new Jakarta umbrella:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws

I'm highly confused: **Why transition to Jakarta / Eclipse led only to partial Maven coordinates changes, most of the EE XML/SOAP stuff still under the old `com.sun.xml`**...

Seems that parent POM leads to:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=com.sun.xml.ws:project:4.0.0:pom -DoutputDirectory=libs


<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws.git</developerConnection>
  <url>https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws</url>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jakarta.*` package represents the [**interface**](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/) (API).

`com.sun.*` package represents the [**implementation**](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws).

This way, when you import/reference **only** the classes of the `jakarta.*` package in your program, then you can effortlessly change the implementation without rewriting your program. E.g. switching the JAX-WS implementation from [Eclipse Metro](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws) to [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) which in turn uses `org.apache.*` instead of `com.sun.*`.

This is the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and it's essentially the same concept as how JDBC drivers work.

Might you find your program using implementation-specific classes directly, i.e. your source code has compile time dependencies on `com.sun.*`, then your program is tight-coupled and unportable across other servers/impls and you might want to fix this tech debt by looking for proper replacements in the `jakarta.*` namespace.

#### See also:

- [In simplest terms, what is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550612/in-simplest-terms-what-is-a-factory/7550752#7550752)
- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee)
- [What is inside com.sun package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package/)
- [Using com.sun.faces with Jakarta EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201991/using-com-sun-faces-with-jakarta-ee/)