# Eclipse Mojarra vs (jakarta.faces » jakarta.faces-api)

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, mojarra

I know that **Mojarra** is Eclipse EE4J implementation of the Jakarta Faces specification.
But what about this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.faces/jakarta.faces-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Obviously it is also an implementation of Jakarta Faces specification implemented by Eclipse EE4J as well: 
https://github.com/jakartaee/faces

So, are they same project or not? and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously it is also an implementation of Jakarta Faces specification implemented by Eclipse EE4J as well

**No**, it is not.

Follow the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.faces/jakarta.faces-api link and [download the JAR file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/faces/jakarta.faces-api/4.0.0/jakarta.faces-api-4.0.0.jar) and inspect its contents using any zip tool. You'll see that it contains only `jakarta.*` classes. It does not contain classes from the implementation package such as `com.sun.faces.*` (Mojarra) or `org.apache.myfaces.*` (MyFaces). In other words, it only contains the API classes not the impl classes.

This JAR file is essentially the "Jakarta Faces specification" part of your first statement:

> I know that Mojarra is Eclipse EE4J implementation of **the Jakarta Faces specification**.

As to,

> So, are they same project or not

**no**, the Mojarra project is here https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra and the Mojarra dependency is here:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

[Download the JAR file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jakarta.faces/4.0.0-M1/jakarta.faces-4.0.0-M1.jar) and inspect its contents. You'll see that it contains `jakarta.*` classes **and** `com.sun.faces.*` classes.

> what is the difference between them?

The API can be included as `<scope>provided</scope>` in projects targeting a full fledged Jakarta EE server which already ships with API+impl out the box. You'll then be able to import `jakarta.faces.*` classes in your code. For those servers, you only need to include the impl (Mojarra or MyFaces) as `<scope>provided</scope>` if you wish to be able to step through the source code in IDE's debugger and/or if you wish to monkeypatch some implementation classes.

But in barebones servletcontainers such as Tomcat, the API dependency as `<scope>compile</scope>` won't work because the implementation is missing. You'll need the impl dependency instead.

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee/)
- [In simplest terms, what is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550612/in-simplest-terms-what-is-a-factory)
- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)
- [Difference between Mojarra and MyFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/difference-between-mojarra-and-myfaces)